# Убрать повторения из комбинаций в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно составить комбинации из цифр без повторений, помогите, пожалуйста усовершенствовать код, нельзя пользоваться itertools:

```
class Solution:
    def permutations(self, nums: list) -> list:
        if len(nums) == 0:
            return []
        elif len(nums) == 1:
            return [nums]
        else:
            res = []
            for i in range(len(nums)):
                x = nums[i]
                xs = nums[:i] + nums[i+1:]
                for p in self.permutations(xs):
                    res.append([x] + p)
            return res
```

инпут такой:

```
1,1,2
```

аутпут такой:

```
1 1 2
1 2 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
2 1 1
2 1 1
```

а должен быть таким:

```
2 1 1
1 2 1
1 1 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно сделать вот так

```
from itertools import permutations

a = "1,1,2" # input
b = a.split(",") # разделение на список 


output = list(set(permutations(b, len(b)))))
```

permutations выводит комбинации, a set чистит от повторения.

сделайте вот так

```
def permutations(nums: list) -> list:
        if len(nums) == 0:
            return []
        elif len(nums) == 1:
            return [nums]
        else:
            res = []
            for i in range(len(nums)):
                x = nums[i]
                xs = nums[:i] + nums[i+1:]
                for p in permutations(xs):
                    if [x] + p not in res:
                        res.append([x] + p)
            return res
```

Comment: itertools  пользоваться нельзя

Comment: тогда просто пользуйтесь set стандартная

Comment: если использовать set(res) выводит ошибку

Comment: сделать как в ответе все работает я его изменил

Answer (score 1):

```
class Solution:
    def permutations(self, nums: list) -> list:
        if len(nums) == 0:
            return []
        elif len(nums) == 1:
            return [nums]
        else:
            res = []
            for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1):
                x = nums[i]
                xs = nums[:i] + nums[i + 1:]
                for p in self.permutations(xs):
                    if [x] + p not in res:
                        res.append([x] + p)
            return res
```

вывод

```
[[2, 1, 1], 
[1, 2, 1], 
[1, 1, 2]]
```